# How to change the value of variables, booleans, and arrays from another class

Tags: java, variables

I have a game and I want to restart it. And I was advised to restore every variable inside the game to default value. The problem is, I don't know how to properly restore every kind of variable, boolean, and array *from another class* but when I run the game, It doesn't change anything. Game doesn't restart.

This is how I did it:

```
private boolean running;
private boolean active;

private int index;
private long timer;

private float xOffset, yOffset;

private Queue<Integer> BaseQueue, KeyQueue;

protected int x, y, count;
protected boolean pickedUp;

private static State currentState;

private int width, height;
private int spawnX, spawnY;

protected float xMove, yMove;

private boolean[] keys, justPressed, cantPress;
private ArrayList<Item> inventoryItems;
public static Item[] items = new Item[256];

public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];
private int[][] tilesArray;    


 public void restartGame() throws Exception{

    active = true;
    running = false;

     index = 0;
     timer = 0;

     xOffset= 0; 
     yOffset=0;

     BaseQueue = null; 
     KeyQueue = null;

     x=0;
     y =0; 
     count = 1;

    width= 0; 
    height = 0;

    spawnX = 100; 
    spawnY=100;

    currentState = null;

    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 0;

    keys = null;
    justPressed = null;
    cantPress = null;

    inventoryItems = null;
    items = null;

    ArrayList<Item> items = null;
    tiles = null;

    tilesArray = null;    

}
```

Here is the code that calls the `restartGame` method:

```
public void tick(){
    if(handler.getKeyManager().restart)
       try {
          restartGame();
    } catch(Exception ioe){
           System.out.print("Error."); }
    if(handler.getKeyManager().exit)
        System.exit(0);
}
```

I don't know if I did anything right. I'm sorry. Please tell what part of code you need in order to help.

Comment: It was working but nothing is happening. When I finish the game and pressed restart, it just goes back to where I was(with the game finished and the player on the last place it was in)

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `restartGame()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can give each variable a value when you create it:

```
protected int x=0, y=0, count=1;
...
```

and then those are the 'default' values.

For boolean, you can set it to what you need like this:

```
private boolean running = false;
private boolean active = true;
```

All the other objects already have a default value of `null`, as all objects are initialized as `null` (unless they are `int`,`double`,`boolean` and so on).

For string, the default value is also null

```
String s;
//doing something with s will throw NullPointerException
```

Comment: Unless it is a String? Lovely. So what do you think is the default value of a String field? :D

Comment: Sure you were. And writing it correctly in the first version was impossible?

Comment: @Tom Don't get me wrong, I shouldn't have posted the answer when it wasn't complete. I wasn't expecting something to come up while answering...

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the following statement as the problem for this question:

> And I was advised to restore every variable inside the game to default value.

When you instantiate this class and you play around with it in your game, it will change values. When you re-instantiate this class then it will recreate the object with the default values again, overwriting the existing one.

For example if you have:

```
Object o = new Object();
o.setThis("whatever");
o.setThat(true);
o.setFoo(1);
o.setBar(0.0f);
```

Then you decide you want to restart the game so you want to reset the values contained in `o` you can simply just reinstantiate it which will set everything to the beginning.

```
Object o = new Object();
... // Do whatever
```

In the constructor for `Object` you can set your default values as you wish. And as for accessing these properties within the Object, I suggest you take a look at [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and use getters and setters.

This sort of an approach is similar to the approach used in `List` when clearing. You can either do:

```
List<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
```

or:

```
List<T>.clear();
```

You're essentially clearing your object for new values again, to refresh the object essentially.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object from a class (and lets say you use it for some time and modify its values), if you need a the object to revert back to its initial states and properties, you can just instantiate a new class and assign it to your already created object.

```
class MyGame {

    // all states and properties
    private int width = 0; // etc . . .
    public void setWidth(int width) {

        this.width = width;
    }
    // etc . . .
}

// create a new game
MyGame myGame = new MyGame();

// modify the object for a while
myGame.setWidth(12); // etc . . .

// you can just reset the object like so,
myGame = new MyGame();
```

Hopefully, java should "garbage-collect" the old object for you.

Comment: You are using `setWidth` like a variable but it's a method.